Counter example to every closed subscheme $\operatorname{Proj} A$ is of the form $\operatorname{Proj}A/I$
I was under the impression that for a positively graded ring $A$ (not necessarily generated in degree $1$) that every closed subscheme of $\operatorname{Proj}A$ was of the $\operatorname{Proj}A/I$. However, I can only find a proof of the case when the irrelevant ideal satisfies $A_+=\sqrt{\langle g_1,\dots, g_n\rangle}$, or equivalently when $\operatorname{Proj}A$ is quasicompact.
So, is there somehow a closed subhscheme $Z$ of say:
$$\mathbb P^\infty_{\mathbb C}=\operatorname{Proj} \mathbb C[x_0,x_1,\dots]$$
such that $Z\not\cong\operatorname{Proj}\mathbb C[x_0,x_1,\dots]/I$ for some homogenous ideal $I$? This would be very confusing to me, as to me a closed subscheme is an equivalence class of closed embeddings $f:Z\rightarrow \mathbb P^\infty_{\mathbb C}$, so $Z$ must be homeomorphic to the vanishing locus of a homogenous ideal, and I believe that I can show that $V(I)$ is homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Proj}A/I$ with no restrictions on $A$:

Let $\pi:A\rightarrow A/I$ be the projection map, where $A/I$ has the induced grading, and $\mathfrak p\in \operatorname{Proj}A/I$. The prime ideal $\pi^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$ is homogenous, as if $a\in \pi^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$ then we write $a$ as:
\begin{align}
a=\sum_d a_d
\end{align}
where $a_d\in A_d$. It follows that $\pi(a)\in \mathfrak p$, and since $\mathfrak p$ is homogenous each $\pi(a_d)$ is in $\mathfrak p$ so each $a_d\in \pi^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$. This defines a map $f:\operatorname{Proj} A/I\rightarrow \operatorname{Proj}A$. Each $\pi^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$ contains $I$ so this map lands in $V(I)$. Via the bijection between prime ideals of $A/I$ and prime ideals of $A$ containing $I$ it follows that this map (when the codomain is restricted to $V(I)$) is a bijection, so it suffices to check that this is continuous and open.
We can do this on the distinguished basis for $\operatorname{Proj}A/I$ and the basis $\{V(I)\cap U_g\}_{g\in A_+^{\hom}}$ for $V(I)$. Let $U_g$ be the projective distinguished open in $\operatorname{Proj} A$, then
$$f^{-1}(V(I)\cap U_g)=f^{-1}(V(I))\cap f^{-1}(U_g)=f^{-1}(U_g)$$
I claim that this is equal to $U_{[g]}$. Suppose $[g]\notin \mathfrak p\subset A/I$, then for all $i\in I$ we must have that $g+i\notin \pi^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$ hence $g\notin \pi^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$. It follows that $\mathfrak p\in U_g$ so $U_{[g]}\subset U_g$. Now let $\mathfrak p\in f^{-1}(U_g)$, then $g\notin \pi^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$, but this implies that $[g]\notin \pi(\pi^{-1}(\mathfrak p))=\mathfrak p$ so $\mathfrak p\in U_{[g]}$. Therefore $f^{-1}(U_g)=U_{[g]}$ and $f$ is continuous.
To show that $f$ is open we claim that $f(U_{[g]})=V(I)\cap U_{g}$, but this is now clear as $f:\operatorname{Proj}A/I\rightarrow V(I)$ is bijective, so since $f^{-1}(V(I)\cap U_g)=U_{[g]}$ we get that $f(f^{-1}(V(I)\cap U_g)=V(I)\cap U_g=U_{[g]}$. It follows that $f$ is a continuous open bijective map and thus a homeomorphism.

If the above is correct, then this would mean that there is a scheme morphism $f:Z\rightarrow \mathbb P^\infty_{\mathbb C}$ such that $Z$ is homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Proj}A/I$ but not isomorphic as a scheme. Therefore the problem would have to lie in the sheaf morphism, which confuses me. In particular, I don't know how I would cook up a closed embedding which ends up being homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Proj}A/I$ but not homeomorphic to it...
If anyone could provide a counter example, or perhaps show why quasicompactness is needed (maybe not needed?) I would be very grateful.

Indeed, as you guessed, there are closed subschemes of $\text{Proj}\ k[x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots]$ which do not correspond to homogeneous ideals. Here is the standard example.
Let $U_j$ be the open subset where the coordinate $U_j$ is nonzero. So $U_j$ is $\text{Spec}\ k[x_1/x_j, x_2/x_j, x_3/x_j, \ldots]$. Let $Z_j$ be the closed subscheme of $U_j$ corresponding to the ideal $\langle x_1/x_j, x_2/x_j, x_3/x_j, \ldots \rangle^j$. (Notice the exponent outside the angle brackets!) Observe that, for $i \neq j$, $Z_i \cap (U_i \cap U_j) = Z_i \cap (U_i \cap U_j) = \emptyset$. So we can define a closed subscheme $Z$ by the property that $Z \cap U_j = Z_j$ for all $j$. The underlying topological space of $Z$ is a disjoint union of countably many points, so $Z$ is not compact.
Now, I will show that the only homogeneous polynomial vanishing on $Z$ is the zero polynomial. Indeed, let $f$ be a nonzero homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$. Then $f$ does not vanish on $Z_j$ for $j>d$.

But aren't the closed subset of $\operatorname{Proj}A$ precisely the vanishing loci of homogenous ideals by definition? So shouldn't this closed set be of the form $V(I)$? or am I missing something?

In particular, is there something wrong with my proof that $V(I)$ is homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Proj}A/I$? (sorry for spam I meant to put this in the first comment)

The closed subsets of $\text{Proj}\ A$ can be described in (at least) two ways (1) they are the sets whose interesection with every $U_i$ is closed (in the Zariski topology on the affine scheme $U_i$ or (2) as the sets $V(I)$, for a homogeneous ideal $I$. The equivalence of these criteria is not obvious; in Vakil's book it is exercise 4.5.M http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjul2724public.pdf . The underlying set of the scheme $Z$ corresponds to the homogeneous ideal $\langle x_i x_j : i \neq j \rangle$. (continued)

However, closed subschemes are only defined by the analogue of criterion (1). This is how you define closed subschemes in any ambient scheme which is defined by gluing open charts.

How do you mean closed subschemes are only defined by the analogue of criterion $(1)$? To me a closed subscheme is essentially the data of a closed immersion $Z\hookrightarrow X$ (up to an isomorophism on $Z$ which makes a diagram commute), so at minimum the domain must be homeomorphic to a closed subset of $X$. From what I wrote in the post, I believe (and may be incorrrect) that any such $Z$ should be homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Proj} A/I$ for some homogenous ideal. This has an obvious scheme structure, so is there somehow another scheme structure which makes the inclusion (continued)

of $V(\langle x_ix_j:i\neq j\rangle)$ a closed embedding but not isomorphic to $\operatorname{Proj}k[x_1,\dots]/\langle x_ix_j:i\neq j\rangle$?

There is nothing wrong with your proof that $V(I)$ is homeomorphic to $\text{Proj}\ A/I$. The point is that there are closed subschemes $Z$ of $\text{Proj}\ A$ which are not of the form $\text{Proj}\ A/I$, because the ideal $I$ of elements of $A$ which vanish on $Z$ is too small, and hence $V(I)$ is too large.

To describe this answer as a closed immersion, take the disjoint union $\bigsqcup_j \text{Spec}\ k[y_1, y_2, \ldots]/\langle y_1, y_2, \ldots \rangle^j$. So, as a topological space, this is a countable discrete set, but with more and more nilpotent thickening as $n$ grows. Put the $j$-th nilpotently thickened point of this discrete set at the point ${ x_i = 0 : i \neq j }$ in $\text{Proj}\ k[x_1, x_2, \ldots]$.

If I am not mistaken, the nilpotency is the only obstruction. If we consider $Y$ a reduced closed subscheme of $\rm{Proj}(A)$, and $I \subseteq A$ a homogeneous ideal such that $Y = V(I)$ (topologically), then $\rm{Proj}(A/\sqrt{I})$ also defines a reduced closed subscheme of $\rm{Proj}(A)$ with the same underlying topological space as $Y$, hence they coincide as schemes.

@DavidESpeyer so the fact that there is no homogenous polynomial which vanishes on each point is the reason this is not a projective scheme, the topological space is still that of the underlying top space of a projective scheme? If this is the case, I think this makes sense to me now thank you

@FrançoisGatine this is the induced reduced subscheme structure right? Where the ideal is determined strictly by the closed subset (hence must be radial in order for the structure to be unique)?

According to both Vakil (Section 4.5.10, http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjul2724public.pdf ) and the Stacks Project (Section 37.50, https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B44 ), a "projective scheme over $k$" is Proj of a ring $A$ where $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra. So neither $Z$ nor its reduction are projective over $k$ by that definition.

Omitting the word "projective scheme", I am saying that $Z$ is not of the form $\text{Proj}\ A$ for a quotient $A$ of $k[x_1, x_2, \ldots]$ (or at least, $Z$ equipped with its embedding into $\text{Proj}\ k[x_1, x_2, \ldots ]$ is not), but that the reduction of $Z$, which has the same underlying space as $Z$, is $\text{Proj}\ k[x_1, x_2, \ldots]/\langle x_i x_j : i \neq j \rangle$.
